# Setting a breakpoint in the for loop cause an error using prototype on array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I run the following code (the code itself doesn't do meaningful stuff since it's a simpler version of my bigger code) on the google apps script editor. When I just run the code, it runs fine. But, when I set a breakpoint in the for loop and run in the debug mode, it runs for the first loop. But, on the second loop, I get a "TypeError: In the object 1.2.3.4.5.6, the function findIndex can't be found" or something like that. Why does this happen? Do I do anything wrong?

```
function myFunction() {
 for (var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
    var s = items.findIndex(5);
    Logger.log(s);
  }
}

Array.prototype.findIndex = function(search){
  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
    for (var j=0; j<10; j++){
      var tmp = this[i][j];
      if (this[i][j] == search) return {row:i, col:j};
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I got the same error.  The array `items` does not have a function inside of it.  You're trying to reference a function inside of an array that has no function object in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
function myFunction() {

 function findIndex(search, array){
  var tmp;

  if(search == "") return false;
  for (var k=0; k<array.length; k++){
    for (var j=0; j<array[k].length; j++){
      tmp = array[k][j];
      if (tmp === search) return {row:k+1, col:j};
    }
  }
  return -1;
 }

 for (var i=0; i < 5; i++){
    var items = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];
    var s = findIndex(5, items);
    Logger.log(s);
  }
}
```

I'm passing the array to the inner function.

Comment: So, the problem was defining array.prototype myself. The function, findIndex, doesn't have to be the inner function. Is that correct?

Comment: You could put the `findIndex()` function outside.